# Xcode PhoneGap: Re-enable landscape orientation (iOS)

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, orientation

I started a project with PhoneGap in XCode and selected just portrait for orientation. Now my client wants to have booth Landscape and Portait available. Thing is I cant find how to change it back!

Can anyone point me in the right direction? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yup I got it:

Under your project file, click the symbol under Target on the left. Have the Summary tab selected and scroll down to find the orientation options.